# Why is /etc/fstab preferred over systemd unit files?

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab, automounting, systemd-mount

The [systemd.mount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) man page says (emphasis mine):

> Mount units may either be configured via unit files, or via `/etc/fstab` (see [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) for details). Mounts listed in `/etc/fstab` will be converted into native units dynamically at boot and when the configuration of the system manager is reloaded. In general, **configuring mount points through `/etc/fstab` is the preferred approach.**

Why is `/etc/fstab` preferred in this case? To my knowledge systemd has replaced the pre-existing configuration methods in many places. Are there downsides to using `.mount` unit files?

Comment: This is conjecture, so I'm responding with it as a comment rather than answer, but I suspect the preference might be due to ubiquity and compatibility- many tools (and indeed administrators) may know to look at `/etc/fstab` instinctively but not so with checking `systemd` configurations.

Comment: AFAIK, the systemd fsck service will run fsck on non-root filesystems only if they're listed in /etc/fstab.

Comment: The configuration manager I use will update /etc/fstab if a file system will be managed.   AFAIK there's not currently a builtin way to manage it through systemctl mounts though special  scripts and commands might be possible - much easier to use fstab.

Comment: `"Are there downsides to using .mount unit files?"` That would seem to follow from the statement you referenced in `man 5 systemd.mount`. Maybe Linus added that line... I've heard he didn't think much of `systemd` :) - at least in the early days. Or, as others have commented, `/etc/fstab` is *simpler*, and if one doesn't need the *"features"* offered by `systemd.mount`, why make mounting a drive more complicated than necessary? But this all sounds like speculation; perhaps the only real answer is one coming from the author of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with CIFS using Kerberos security (sec=krb5) won't work via fstab for RHEL 7. *x* due to the `cifs.upcall` on CIFS-Utils version 6.2 (standard for RHEL 7. *x*). CIFS-Utils version 6.2 only allows KRB credential cache lookup in `/tmp` – this is fine if your company uses the default location,
but our company uses a different directory to store the Credential Cache.

The workaround is to uninstall CIFS-Utils 6.2x and replace it with the one packaged on RHEL 8.*x* via RPM install and not via `yum` since no dependency. 
However, my company does not allow this, so I have to craft a workaround.

This is where I created three files under the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` directory.

1. `filename.service`
2. `filename.mount`
3. `filename.timer`

Where:

- #1 is a service to copy the credential cache to `/tmp`
- #2 is to mount the CIFS – but you need to add the `filename.service` to run first
- #3 is to start the timer that will copy the credential cache either hourly or daily so when the mount got unmounted due to an issue you can remount it with no issue

Comment: does this really answer why the systemd documentation prefers fstab?